# How to draw timelines in a tree table

Tags: swing, user-interface, javafx

I am writing an analyzer to visually see where my application is spending time. The interface that I am trying to achieve (see below) is something similar to a tree table with

- lines or boxes to denote response time.
- be a collapsible tree like graph
- the ability to display metrics in the table columns (e.g., start time, cost, etc)
- the ability to display the labels or description and metrics on the left and lines on the right

I create the following diagram (see below) in R -- unfortunately, although the graph production is automated, the approach is not interactive. I was wondering if you could suggest a better way -- maybe a tree table. I looked at many Swing, JavaFx tree table examples. I have not seen an example that has lines (time lines) in a tree table.

[image]

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might wish to take a look at the third party (and commercially licensed), [FlexGanntFX](http://flexganttfx.com).

Comment: thanks - let me check that out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can show any node in a `TreeTableCell` using the `grahic` property in javaFX. This includes `Rectangle`s.

This is a simple example of showing bars in a column using `Rectangles`:

```
// Arrays in TreeItems contain {startValue, endValue} (both positive)
TreeItem<int[]> root = new TreeItem<>(new int[]{0, 10});
root.getChildren().addAll(new TreeItem<>(new int[]{0, 5}), new TreeItem<>(new int[]{5, 10}));
TreeTableView<int[]> ttv = new TreeTableView<>(root);

// Column displaying bars based on data of TreeItem. Do not use this as
// the first column, otherwise the alignment be off depending on the
// distance to the root.
TreeTableColumn<int[], int[]> column = new TreeTableColumn<>();
column.setCellValueFactory(c -> c.getValue().valueProperty());

final double BAR_SIZE = 20;
column.setCellFactory((t) -> new TreeTableCell<int[], int[]>() {

    // the bar
    private final Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(0, 10);

    {
        setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.GRAPHIC_ONLY);

        // bar invisible by default
        rectangle.setVisible(false);
        setGraphic(rectangle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void updateItem(int[] item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);
        if (!empty && item != null) {
            // resize and display bar, it item is present
            rectangle.setWidth((item[1] - item[0]) * BAR_SIZE);
            rectangle.setTranslateX(item[0] * BAR_SIZE);
            rectangle.setVisible(true);
        } else {
            // no item -> hide bar
            rectangle.setVisible(false);
        }
    }
});

// add a columns new column
// add a additional empty column at the start to prevent bars being
// aligned based on distance to the root
ttv.getColumns().addAll(new TreeTableColumn<>(), column);
```

#### Things you need to do

- use a data type different to `int[]`; the cell value factory and `TreeTableCell` needs to be adjusted accordingly; an example of a more complex model can be found e.g. in the oracle tutorial: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/user-interface-tutorial/tree-table-view.htm
- Choose better colors; These colors could e.g. be stored in a `Map` and created if a new one is needed.
- add additional colums

Comment: thanks. Let me try it today. I will let you know if this works.